# Spread calculation across multiple servers

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a formula which takes approximately 0.5s to calculate. However, I need this calculation to be executed 1 million times with different values. An example of the formula (simplified):

```
y = a + b
```

In which I have 1 million combinations of `a` and `b` which all need to be calculated. These 1 million combinations are saved in a list called `combinations`. I work with Python.

My idea is to spin up an AWS instance for every 100.000 calculations, so in this case I'll need 10. Then the idea is to divide the `combinations` list into 10 pieces (`part1 = combinations[:100000]` etc.). Then I have to send every AWS instance the subset of combinations.

But how can I do this best? My idea was to have a shared volume that is accessible for all instances and on that volume I put the `calculate.py` script which I call via SSH:

`ssh user@instance python calculcate.py`

Or is celery maybe a better way to do this? Or maybe another way?

*Edit: I did some testing and Celery seems the way to go.*

Comment: To me, this sounds like it might an excellent opportunity to rewrite the function in C and call this from Python. Speedups of 10, 100, or 1000 times can often result. Sometimes speedup is very minimal though, it all depends up the details of you function. There are a number of ways to do this. You might also try PyPy which can give significant performance advantages and is low-effort since all you need in a different Python interpreter.

Comment: @GaryWalker thanks for your reply. It is a linear regression (statsmodels OLS) which is not supported by Pypy, so I prefer to keep working with CPython.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pathos` to set up a ssh-tunnel, then submit the function to several servers using the `pathos` fork of `parallelpython` -- or just use the tunnel from `pathos` and use something else like `rpyc` or `zmq` to connect to the different servers through the tunnel.

See: [Python Multiprocessing with Distributed Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876898/python-multiprocessing-with-distributed-cluster/26948258#26948258)