# Converting serial to parallel to multi-machine

Tags: python

I had the following code running serially to request a bunch of urls:

```
# takes 5 hours
data = []
for url in urls:
    data.append(request_url(url))
```

I then converted it to run in parallel using multiprocessing:

```
# takes 50 minutes
p = Pool(20)
data = p.map(request_url, urls)
```

If I wanted to improve the speed on this, how would I then spread this process across multiple servers, what would be a good method to do this?

Comment: There is as yet no "plain vanilla standard" about how best to distribute work among multiple servers.  If you totally trust your servers and network, `RabbitMQ` may offer one approach; if you don't, something more solid such as `MapReduce`, see e.g https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/3-MapReduce-for-Python , or its popular dialect `Hadoop`, may free you from substantial "housekeeping work".  But it's important that you consider and express what constraints, exactly, you need to satisfy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pathos` (and it's sister package `pyina`), to help you figure out exactly how you wanted to distribute the code in parallel.

`pathos` provides a unified API for parallel processing across threading, multiprocessing, and sockets.  The API provides `Pool` objects which have blocking, non-blocking iterative, and asynchronous `map` and `pipe` methods.  `pyina` extends this API to `MPI` and schedulers like `torque` and `slurm`.  You can, generally, nest these constructs so you have heterogeneous and hierarchical parallel distributed computing.

You shouldn't need to modify your code at all to use `pathos` (and `pyina`).

There are a few examples of this on SO, including these:
[Python Multiprocessing with Distributed Cluster Using Pathos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939704/python-multiprocessing-with-distributed-cluster-using-pathos/26941850#26941850) and 
[Python Multiprocessing with Distributed Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876898/python-multiprocessing-with-distributed-cluster/26948258#26948258)

and in the `examples` directories found in `pathos`, `pyina`, and `mystic` -- found here:
https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: I should also mention that `Ipython parallel` and `scoop` are both coming along (catching up?) in their hierarchical parallel computing, and may soon provide equivalent methods to what I mention above.  The examples I give use `pathos.pp` (parallel python), while `Ipython` favors `zmq`.  I've also used `rpyc` before as an alternative, but didn't find it as lightweight as `pp`.