# pathos distributed computing not connecting to remote host

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I am trying to spawn processes to a remote node. The code resembles the answer I have found 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876898/python-multiprocessing-with-distributed-cluster?lq=1)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

from pathos.pp import ParallelPythonPool as Pool
def sleepy_squared(x):
    from time import sleep
    sleep(1.0)
    import socket

    print(socket.gethostname())

    return x**2

p = Pool(8, servers=('151.49.140.246:1234',))
# use an asynchronous parallel map
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
res = p.amap(sleepy_squared, x)

print(res.get())
```

The problem is that when I run this code, `pathos` keeps running on my local machine ignoring the servers attribute. I would like the function to run only on the remote server (or crash if not available).
In order to configure the server I'm launching the file `ppserver.py` (found in the Scripts folder in the Anaconda installation). I have tried launching it with multiple configurations

```
python ppserver.py -d
python ppserver.py -i 127.0.0.1 -p 1234 -d
python ppserver.py -i 151.49.140.246 -p 1234 -b 255.255.255.0 -d
```

(the last one doesn't even work)

I can't understand honestly if the problem is with the configuration server side (the server is listening though) or the client side (servers are ignored) or both.

Comment: Ask @Mike McKerns according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948258/2987828